# How to work with cursors in workbench with mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using 5.2 35 Ce workbench for MySQL and I cannot get anywhere trying to work with Cursors.  I tried this:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM WASP.COMPANY;
```

For pete's sake I copied the command from an example in the MySQL help site. And it gives me a syntax on DECLARE.  Does Workbench even allow the use of the DECLARE statement?

[image: Image of the DECLARE statement]

Dennis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursors are only allowed in the context of a stored routine, not as standalone statements.